# Weird bug using fopen() inside a function

Tags: c

I've been looking around for like 4hours and cannot find where the problem is.

I got this function over here which is supposed to open a file.
In the function I successfully get into the `!= NULL` condition thus returning 1, then in the main the value of my pointer test_file_1 is null (and then segfault when fclose)

I do not understand why because I am assigning the return value of fopen to my pointer !!

Here is the prototype :

```
/*
 * Open a file and save its file pointer into file_to_load
 * If it worked, returns 1
 * Else, 0
 *
 * Prints its own error message, so you only have to use the return 
 * value to set the program behavior as wished
 *  
 * filename : name of the file (+ path if needed) 
 * file_to_load : the file to be loaded
 *
 */
int load_file(char* filename, FILE* file_to_load);
```

And here is the function by itself :

```
int load_file(char* filename, FILE* file_to_load) 
{
    //r is for read-only mode, we do not want to let the program edit the file
    //We will only save when told (using save_file)

    if( (file_to_load = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL )
    {       
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, THE_FILE);
        fprintf(stderr, filename);
        fprintf(stderr, CANT_BE_OPENED);
        // Should include the error number for convenience

        return 0;
     }
}
```

And .. here is the use in the main :

```
FILE* test_file_1 = NULL;

//Closed only if exists or else .. segfault
if ( (load_file("../bin/test", test_file_1)) == 1)
{

        fclose(test_file_1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference.

That means a function always gets a copy of its arguments, and changing its copy has no effect on the expression used on calling.

Use additional indirection, here the modified lines (each has exactly one `*` or `&` more):

```
int load_file(char* filename, FILE** file_to_load);
int load_file(char* filename, FILE** file_to_load)
    if( (*file_to_load = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL )
if ( (load_file("../bin/test", &test_file_1)) == 1)
```

BTW: It would be better to return the file as the return-value, unless you need the return-value for something else or there are other reasons not shown in the example.

Comment: Or use references (at least i would recommend this!)

Comment: @Etixpp: That would be in C++, not in C.

Comment: I am using the return value as a check to know if the file has been opened or if it didn't work, but I guess I could directly check if the pointer is NULL or not.

As for the additional indirection I do not really get it, I mean I know that C is pass-by-value, but I always figured that the code I used would work. 
  
I come from java haha. 

Anyway, I will try your code, thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah, it is finally working, thanks a lot for your answer. 

I was pretty sure that giving a new value to my pointer in the function would modify it outside too. 

Guess I still got a lot to learn !

Comment: @Hello_world "pass by value" means that the variable in the function is a different variable to the one that is "outside"

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yeah, I know, but I got somewhat confused by the fact it was a pointer. 

I mean, I was thinking that it would pass the address of that pointer thus allowing me to modify it the way I wanted. 

Then, I re-read only one sentence on my K&R book which made me realize the dumbness of my mistake : 

" A pointer is a variable which contains the address of another variable. " 

So well, my variable is NULL so I have a passed a pointer which is pointing on nothing.  
It's passed by value, but I got no address to cling on as it does not have anything inside.

Comment: @MattMcNabb 
If I was passing an already initialized FILE pointer, I would have been able to work on it as is. Am I right ?

Comment: @Hello_world you could pass that pointer to other library functions expecting a `FILE *`, if that's what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program which pretty much does what you want.

```
int load_file(char *filename, FILE *file_to_load){
 file_to_load = fopen(filename, "r");
 if(file_to_load !=0)
  return 1;
 else
  return 0;
 }
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 FILE file_to_load;
 if(load_file(argv[1],&file_to_load) == 1)
  printf("File exists\n");
 else
  printf("Error loading the given file\n");
 }
```

I have taken the file as a command line argument and changed the error messages but you can alter it according to your requirements.